# Show available cash in a Yahoo Finance portfolio

Tags: stocks, yahoo-finance

I have built a stock portfolio in Yahoo Finance.  I want to show my available cash along with my individual stocks.  How do I show my available cash in my Yahoo Finance stock portfolio?  I have tried "$$" and "$$CASH", but neither works.

Comment: Go to 'My Holdings' -> Add Symbol -> type USD=X and add the amount under shares.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "My Holdings".
Click on "add symbols"
Type CASH in box